# Google apps script create trigger programmaticaly with parameter in function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Currently we can create programmatic triggers using [ScriptApp.newTrigger(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))
But what if we want to pass a parameter to this function?

I can't seem to find out a way to do this. One way I can think of is to store the value in script properties. But then this will fail if we have multiple dynamic triggers(in which case only the last written script property will be applied to the function).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the parametrized functions from the trigger, create non-parametrized functions that call them with the corresponding parameters. Something like the following

```
function myHelperFunction_1() {
  myFunction('Hello America!');
}

function myHelperFunction_2() {
  myFunction('Hello Europe!');
}

function myFunction(message) {
  Logger.log(message);
}
```

Instead of calling myFunction, the triggers should call myHelperFunction_1 and myHelperFunction_2